# Composing multiple Try objects in Scala/Play

Tags: scala, playframework

We have a Scala/Play application in which we have several implicit classes that create Try objects from the Request, e.g.

```
implicit class RequestUtils[+T](req: Request[T]) {
  def user: Try[User] = // pull the User from the Session, or throw an UnauthorizedException
  def paging: Try[Paging] = // create a Paging object, or throw an IllegalArgumentException
}
```

We then access the wrapped objects via flatMaps

```
def route(pathParam: String) = BasicAction {
  request => 
    request.user.flatMap(user => 
      request.paging.flatMap(paging => 
        Try{ ... }
))}
```

And finally, an ActionBuilder generates a SimpleResult from the Try

```
case class BasicRequest[A](request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)

class BasicActionBuilder extends ActionBuilder[BasicRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (BasicRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    block(BasicRequest(request))
  }
}

def BasicAction[T](block: BasicRequest[AnyContent] => Try[T]) = {
  val f: BasicRequest[AnyContent] => SimpleResult = (req: BasicRequest[AnyContent]) =>
    block(req) match {
      case Success(s) => Ok(convertToJson(s))
      case Failure(e: UnauthorizedException) => Unauthorized(e.getMessage)
      case Failure(e: Exception) => BadRequest(e.getMessage)
      case Failure(t: Throwable) => InternalServerError(e.getMessage)
    }

  val ab = new BasicActionBuilder
  ab.apply(f)
}
```

We're trying to find a way to essentially compose multiple Try objects together (or something along those lines - we're not wedded to using Trys) - the flatMaps are working fine for one or two Trys, but nesting them more than that hampers program readability.  We can manually compose the objects together, e.g.

```
case class UserAndPaging(user: User, paging: Paging)

implicit class UserAndPagingUtils[+T](req: Request[T]) {
  def userAndPaging: Try[UserAndPaging] = req.user.flatMap(user => req.paging.flatMap(paging => UserAndPaging(user, paging))
}
```

but that's going to result in an explosion of case class + implicit class def combinations.  Ideally I'd like to be able to compose multiple Try objects together in an ad hoc fashion, e.g.

```
def route(pathParam: String) = BasicAction {
  request => compose(request.user, request.paging).flatMap(userWithPaging => ...)
}
```

and have a Try[User with Paging] magically composed for me, but I have no idea how I'd go about doing this - I've been wrestling with the type system to try to assign a meaningful type to "compose" without any success.

How can I compose multiple Try objects together, or something equivalent using another language construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Try`s can be [used in for-comprehensions](http://www.naildrivin5.com/scalatour/wiki_pages/ForComprehensions), since they have a `flatMap` function:

```
def route(pathParam: String) = BasicAction { request =>
  val userWithPaging =
    for {
      user <- request.user
      paging <- request.paging
    } yield {
      doSomethingWith(user, paging)
    } 
}
```

Comment: ... and don't forget that a `Future[T]` is essentially a `Try[T]` that hasn't finished yet - we made the decision to have all our service-level calls return Futures, and it's been great. You get all that `for`-complehension goodness, plus it fits in beautifully with Play's asynchronous support. Even if a particular service doesn't really need to be async, it's so easy to wrap the result in `Future.successful()`, you may as well! :-)